# Bokeh installation on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: installation, python, python3

Hi have any one tried installing Bokeh on a Raspberry Pi?

I get this error when I try to generate a plot into an html file:

```
python3 test1.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test1.py", line 1, in <module>
    from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/bokeh/plotting/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    from . import figure as _figure
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/bokeh/plotting/figure.py", line 26, in <module>
    from ..core.properties import Any, Auto, Either, Enum, Int, List, Seq, Instance, String, Tuple
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/bokeh/core/properties.py", line 255, in <module>
    from .property.dataspec import AngleSpec; AngleSpec
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/bokeh/core/property/dataspec.py", line 40, in <module>
    from .visual import FontSize, MarkerType
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/bokeh/core/property/visual.py", line 29, in <module>
    import PIL.Image
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 94, in <module>
    from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: libopenjp2.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

It's now installed with pip3 but I have also tried pip, it's installed on a vanilla RPI image.

To me it seems like a package is missing, but I'm not a Python and also Bokeh expert.

Answer (score 0):

A .so file(shared object) is a compiled library file in Linux - akin to Windows' DLL(dynamic linked library) files. It looks like one of the dependencies in your project requires the `libopenjp2.so.7` library. Try making sure it's installed with:

```
sudo apt-get install libopenjp2-7
```

You could then try checking the Linux shared library cache to see if it's in there.

```
ldconfig -p | grep 'libopenjp2.so.7'
```

Which should give you something like:

```
libopenjp2.so.7 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenjp2.so.7
```

If you don't see anything, try updating the cache with:

```
sudo ldconfig
```

Comment: Still getting the same result, I have tried uninstalling libopenjp2-7 and reinstalling it just to be sure.

Comment: Odd, but you might need to update your `so` cache. Editing.

Comment: Now it works I tried a clean install, when bokeh was installing it failed installation of Pillow. The reason for that fail was libjpeg, so thanks for help :-)